# consuming password protected feeds with RSS Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, rss

I've been using the asp.net rss toolkit to consume rss feeds.  it works great except for password protected feeds. Does anyone know how to supply credentials to the toolkit when it's making a request?

thanks

Comment: Did you ever find any way to do this?

Comment: i didn't - we eventually chalked it up as a limitation of rsstoolkit, and hence as a limitation of our application